# How cypher chooses the best plan?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

My question is about how cypher chooses the best plan in a query. Consider the following query:

```
MATCH (a:Label1)-[r:RELTYPE]->(b:Label1), (z:Label2)
WHERE a.id='targetId' AND z.id = r.key
RETURN a, z, b
```

Also, I have indexes defined on Label1:id and Label2:id.
I expected that cypher used a kind of join between r and z and used the defined index, but it chooses a cartesian product plan (I can't afford a cartesian product because each label has millions of nodes). The plan (based on cost) is the following:

```
Projection
  |
  +Filter(0)
    |
    +CartesianProduct
      |
      +Filter(1)
      |  |
      |  +Expand(All)
      |    |
      |    +NodeIndexSeek
      |
      +NodeByLabelScan
```

Then I tried modifying the query:

```
MATCH (a:Label1)-[r:RELTYPE]->(b:Label1)
WHERE a.id='targetId'
WITH a, b, r.key as rkey
MATCH (z:Label2)
WHERE z.id = rkey
RETURN a, z, b
```

Now the plan and the execution time are what I was expecting, and it uses both indexes. But I still wonder why neo4j don't make the same plan for both queries. The new plan is:

```
Projection(0)
  |
  +Apply
    |
    +Projection(1)
    |  |
    |  +Filter
    |    |
    |    +Expand(All)
    |      |
    |      +NodeIndexSeek(0)
    |
    +NodeIndexSeek(1)
```

I know I can define an intermediate/auxiliar node to point but I want to analyze both cases. I think cypher should consider the second plan in the first query and I want to know why it doesn't.